# Wiring a circuit that goes from a switch to a light to a split dual receptacle to a light to an outlet

Tags: electrical, wiring, basement, circuit

I'm pretty new to DIY stuff, and while I've changed light fixtures and switches a few times, my electrical knowledge is a little more limited when it comes to the more complicated stuff. A friend was helping me with a room remodel in our basement but wasn't able to finish, and now he's had some things come up so I can't get him back here anytime soon to finish.

Basically, like the title says, we've got a single-pole switch that will control both lights and the bottom outlet on the first duplex receptacle, but the other receptacle and the top outlet of the first one should be live regardless of the switch position. The wire from the switch to the light to the split receptacle is 12/3 wire, and I'm unsure if I need 12/3 from there onto the rest  of it, and in either case, I'm not positive which wire goes where from the split receptacle.

I've attached a rough sketch below, but please let me know if clarification is needed.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Your black is always hot/live.  Your red is a switch hot.  Red goes to all devices you want to be controlled by the switch.  Black(no red) goes to all devices that you want always hot(outlets), or to devices controlled by another switch.  Red can end at last switched device.

Comment: Do you **want** to have 1/2 outlet switched? Code requires switched outlet **or** hardwired light, and most people I know (at least "me") don't want to have the outlet be switched once they have a hardwired light switched.

Comment: Okay, nice. So the red would go to the brass screw on the light and end there? Where does the black wire go from the top hot outlet on the split receptacle?

Comment: And I do want the half switched outlet since the goal was to have a table lamp that's part of the room's lighting.

Comment: The red goes to everything you to be on that switch, light, split outlet, etc.  The black goes to everything not on the switch, always hot split outlet and/or other always hot outlets on that circuit.